# Gradle errror ERROR: Manifest merger failed :

Tags: android, gradle

> ERROR: Manifest merger failed : Attribute
>   application@appComponentFactory
>   value=(android.support.v4.app.CoreComponentFactory) from
>   [com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0]
>   AndroidManifest.xml:22:18-91  is also present at
>   [androidx.core:core:1.0.0] AndroidManifest.xml:22:18-86
>   value=(androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory).   Suggestion: add
>   'tools:replace="android:appComponentFactory"' to  element
>   at AndroidManifest.xml:16:5-153:19 to override.

Comment: Do you have multiple modules in your project?

Comment: Have you used tools:replace="android:appComponentFactory", as suggested by error ?

Comment: Post your build.gradle file

Answer (score 0):

Do you added/upgrade a dependency which uses androidx.
There are 2 solutions.

1. Migrate your project to [Androidx](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx)
2. Change dependency version to which not use androidx

You should post your build.gradle